# How do I unbind Super key from menu in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I just installed Lubuntu 11.10.  I spend quite a bit of time in Emacs, and I have a bunch of key bindings that rely on the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. However, Lubuntu captures the <kbd>Super</kbd> key press and opens the main menu every time. This is quite frustrating.

How I do I unbind this super key behavior? I've tried tweaking lubuntu-rc.xml with no luck.

Comment: OK. **BE CAREFUL**. The relevant code is buried in the middle of a long, unbroken line and is very hard to see, but it _IS_ there in your `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`.

Answer (score 4):

Editing .config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml (Lubuntu 12.04) worked here. It's line 177, and the original relevant part looked like this: `<keybind key="Super_L"`. Changed it to `<keybind key=""`, logged out/in, and the Super key does nothing.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: In the `lubuntu-rc.xml` that comes with Lubuntu 13.04, there's no entry with the string "Super".

Comment: @vasa1 thanks for commenting. Unfortunately, I've only tested Lubuntu 12.04, and have no first hand experience with 13.04 at all.

Comment: But Openbox still recognizes the use of `Super_L` in Lubuntu 13.04. Someone decided to use just [Super_L to open the terminal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78018/15760) (although the OS and Openbox version weren't specified). I verified that that works in Lubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

For more recent LXQt versions, delete the `Super_L` entry in the shortcut configs, or delete:

```
[Super_L.33]
Comment=Show/hide main menu
Enabled=false
path=/panel/mainmenu/show_hide
```

in `~/.config/lxqt/globalkeyshortcuts.conf`.

Works for me in Lubuntu 20.04.

Comment: does one needs to restart the system or simply logout and relogin ?

Comment: I haven't done it in a while, but I guess logging in and out should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is binded into the lxqt *shortcut keys* menu (Global Action Manager) to `Super_L`, so you **must** first **disable** or edit the entry there. After this, all Super Key (W-) bindings in `*rc.xml` files will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Compiz Config Settings Manager to edit the Ubuntu Unity Plugin. On the Behaviour tab, there's a keybinding for "key to show the launcher".