# Bind the windows key to Lubuntu start menu

Tags: shortcut-keys, lubuntu

I am running Lubuntu 11.10. By default the main menu is bound to Alt+F1 (A-F1) which works. Here is the relevant code from `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`

```
<keybind key="A-F1">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxpanelctl menu</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

This works. When I hit Alt+F1, I can see the start menu.

If I change the keys to "Windows key + M" (W-m), I can pull up the start menu using Win+M

```
<keybind key="W-m">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxpanelctl menu</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

However, I cannot bind the start menu to the Windows key alone. If I try replacing "W-m" by "W", the "W" alphabet key gets bound to the start menu. If I try "W-" nothing happens, I have tried the "Super" option too but to no avail.

How can I bind the Lubuntu main menu to the windows Key?

I have been through some relevant lubuntu questions, like this one, which tries to do the opposite.
[How do I unbind Super key from menu in Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73043/how-do-i-unbind-super-key-from-menu-in-lubuntu)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I managed to just get this to work with 'Super_L', not 'Super'.  Hope that works.  You could also set 'Super_R' to do the same thing, if you have one.

Comment: I remember seeing Super_L when I was searching for a solution, but thought it referred to Win+L key. Ah! it refers to the left Windows key. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to get the super key to 'toggle' the menu? Currently, it would only open it, and I wouldn't be able to close it if I pressed again.

Comment: @levesque [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661724/toggle-lxpanelctrl-menu-in-lubuntu?lq=1), if you haven't seen it and still need it.

Comment: Is there a way to close the menu again by pressing the same key?

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Super_L</kbd> worked for me

```
<keybind key="Super_L">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxpanelctl menu</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: how can do refresh it in my bash? should I reboot? I've tried lxpanelctl restart, but it dont work

Comment: Fix confirmed working on Lubuntu 14.04,  
but destroys Win + ArrowLeft, 
and other keybindings to position windows on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu 10.x

In terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu --type string "Super_L"
```

From: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27038/use-the-windows-key-for-the-start-menu-in-ubuntu-linux-10.04/

Comment: Did not work on Lubuntu 14.04.