# How do I change the copy and paste keyboard shortcuts on Lubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu 12.10 installed on my macbook pro and I am new to linux. I want to change the Lubuntu keyboard shortcuts for copying and pasting. I want to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. I want this to work on all applications like the lxterminal, web browser, text-editor, etc.

Comment: Try this: press `alt+F2`, and then type `lxkeymap`. Choose your country from the left column and then `English (Macintosh)` from the right column and then click `Apply` and close the window. Log out and log back in and see what happens. But **please keep a note of the original settings** in case you need to revert. I don't use a Mac myself and therefore cannot guarantee that this suggestion will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` document. Make a backup, just in case, then edit the file. It is fairly straight forward - you should be able to edit the individual command button functions, as they come with identifiers in the text above. You can map any action to a key, or combination of keys.

For an example of how to adjust the code, for a similar function, see this post:

[Bind the windows key to Lubuntu start menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79557/bind-the-windows-key-to-lubuntu-start-menu)