# Toggle lxpanelctrl menu in lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I want my windows key (or super_l) to toggle the lubuntu menu. I'm able to open it with the windows key after adding the key binding from the question below, but so far I haven't found a way to close it by pressing the same key again. A comment in said question here asked about the same thing in november 2011, but after googling I haven't found a solution. Does anyone know if it's possible?

[Bind the windows key to Lubuntu start menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79557/bind-the-windows-key-to-lubuntu-start-menu)

Comment: That might be another issue for another question. In sublime text (as an example), I have a binding for ctrl+alt+r, and one for ctrl+alt+r+r. It works like this: If I click ctrl+alt+r nothing happens until I either click r again (activating the second key binding) or click _any other key than r_ (activating the first key binding).

Comment: My english isnt that good so I didnt understand the 5th step. Where should I add "python3 /path/to/click_menu.py -run" excactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Alternative way to toggle the menu

This answer is only "half" of the answer that was posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605234/key-for-expanding-application-menu-in-gnome-classic-for-14-04) . Since that question was on `Gnome`, and tagged likewise, I think it is legitimate to post a slightly edited version here to cover `Lubuntu` (`lxde`), or any other window manager.

I tested it on `Lubuntu 14.04`, and (as expected) did exactly what it should do.

The solution is actually a script that you can easily set up to automatically (virtually) click on *any* position on your screen, including the menu. Since clicking the menu once will open it, clicking it again will close it, placing the command under your key, as you did, will do exactly what you are after.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import os

option = sys.argv[1]
datafile = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".run_click")

def get_mousepos():
    cursordata = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    return [d.split(":")[1] for d in cursordata[:2]]

if option == "-run":
    try:
        data = open(datafile).read()
        coords = (" ").join([l for l in data.splitlines()])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        message = "Please run the command: 'run_click -set' first, to set the click position"
        subprocess.Popen(["zenity", "--info", "--text", message])
    else:
        cmd1 = "xdotool mousemove "+coords; cmd2 = "xdotool click 1"; cmd3 = "xdotool mousemove "+(" ").join(get_mousepos())
        for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
            time.sleep(0.05)
elif option == "-set":
    open(datafile, "wt").write(("\n").join(get_mousepos()))
```

#### About the script; how to set up

1. The script needs `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `click_menu.py`
3. Now you need to make the script remember the menu position to (virtually) click:

   The script needs to be run with the option `-set`, with the mouse in position:

   - open a terminal window, type the command:

     ```
     sleep 5 && python3 /path/to/click_menu.py -set
     ```
   - immediatley position the mouse above the menu (do not click)
   - after the 5 seconds have passed, the menu position is "remembered". The position is written to an invisible file, so you will only need to do this once.
4. Test if all works fine with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/click_menu.py -run
   ```

   [image]

   The menu should open, as shown in th image above.
5. If all works fine add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/click_menu.py -run
   ```

   to the key, as you did with the other command you mentioned in your question. Now pressing the key should toggle the menu.

Comment: Nice solution! I can't test it right now, but I will tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: @L42 just curious, but did you try?

Comment: Haha, just as you said man. Thanks a lot! I never thought about solving it like this.

Comment: @L42 perfect, great that you like it :)

Comment: Sorry, I answered too fast. It works for opening the menu, not for closing it. I don't understand why, because clicking twice on the menu manually opens and then closes it. My key binding looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/2SDCh1mg).

Comment: @L42 huh? It does work here... I'll post a link to an edited version of the script (tomorrow) to find out where it goes wrong. Possibly (probably) a timing issue that needs a small fix.

Comment: Thanks. Doing [this](http://pastebin.com/TWNgLbDj) just to test worked. No clue why it doesn't work when I click Super_L twice.

Comment: @L42 AHA, that makes clear the script works fine, it must be something with processing the shortcut.

Comment: This was ingenuous.